Does the zweihander sentinel’s armament shield feature allow non-reach attacks with reach weapons?
The zweihander sentinel archetype for the warder has a feature called armament shield:

When wielding a one-handed weapon in two hands or a two-handed weapon, the weapon is treated as a light shield for the purposes of performing a shield bash attack on an opponent. The warder smashes with the butt of a spear-haft, the pommel of a greatsword, or the broadside of her axe. All are essentially the same and are treated as light shields for the purposes of shield bash attacks or martial maneuvers to be used with a weapon of this type (such as Iron Tortoise maneuvers that require a shield to function). The zweihander sentinel may always use her armament shield as an off-hand weapon, even if she has already attacked with her weapon in both hands.

If you have a reach weapon, can you use this to attack inside your reach? If so, how would the damage be calculated? As you are wielding the weapon with both hands, would you add strength 1½× to damage?

Thank you for the edit. It clarifies my question a lot.

Yes, but damage calculated as a light shield bash

the weapon is treated as a light shield for the purposes of performing a shield bash attack

(Armament shield description)
This statement isn’t limited or qualified in any way, so yes, a light shield does not have reach, and so can attack inside your weapon’s usual reach—but cannot attack at that usual reach. So a Medium zweihander sentinel with a polearm attacks with the blade at 10 feet and attacks with the armament shield bash at 5 feet.
As for damage, that is also handled exactly like an actual bash with an actual light shield. So its base damage is 1d3 unless you have the Improved Shield Bash feat (which would apply), and it’s bludgeoning, regardless of how much or what type(s) of damage your weapon would ordinarily deal. Any magic on the weapon would apply, so if you have a +1 flaming greatsword, your armament shield bash deals damage as a +1 flaming light shield.
Finally, the Strength bonus is defined by the following rules:

For the purpose of penalties on attack rolls, treat a light shield as a light weapon.

(Light shield, steel or wooden, description)

Add the wielder’s Strength modifier to damage rolls for melee attacks with a light weapon if it’s used in the primary hand, or half the wielder’s Strength bonus if it’s used in the off hand. Using two hands to wield a light weapon gives no advantage on damage; the Strength bonus applies as though the weapon were held in the wielder’s primary hand only.

(Light weapons description)
The armament shield counts as a light shield, a light shield is a light weapon, and light weapons don’t benefit from having two hands: you add only 1×Str, not 1½×Str. There is a bit of awkwardness where armament shield says “The zweihander sentinel may always use her armament shield as an off-hand weapon, even if she has already attacked with her weapon in both hands,” so if you do that, you’re wielding it with two hands but it counts as an off-hand weapon—that one will have to be adjudicated by your GM, if you use two-weapon fighting to get one or more extra attacks and designate your armament shield as an off-hand weapon. It’s probably meant to be ½×Str but there’s just enough wiggle room to argue that it maybe is 1×Str even then, rules-as-written. Remember, though, that the off-hand designation only applies during a full attack in which you utilize two-weapon fighting, though: even if you only add ½×Str to damage during your turn because you use two-weapon fighting, you add 1×Str to any attacks of opportunity you make with it during the rest of the round.
